# How to modify multiple CSS value with scroll distance

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I need some help trying to figure out what is the best way to modify different CSS values using the scroll position. I think JavaScript might be the answer, but I cant find an example anywhere.

I am looking to modify the "top:" value of the different ids depending on how much the user has scrolled down.

for example: 
As the user scrolls down the top value for the #one id, should be over written to a negative number until it reaches -300px. At that point it the top value of the id #two should be modified with a negative value until it reaches -600px.

As the user scrolls this change in top value will create a scroll animation, similar to a deck of cards.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="two"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="three"></div>
</div>

.outer{
  width 500px;
  height:900px;
  background:black; 
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.inner {
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto;
  height:300px;
  border:solid 10px white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#one{z-index:3;background:red;top:-800px}
#two{z-index:2;background:blue;}
#three{z-index:1;background:green;}
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to get to.

https://codepen.io/lammworks/pen/BrxRrP

Comment: My recommendation is to look into Less client side compilation. It isnt recommended for production sites but I've tested it and it's really fast. You basically add all your Less source files to the site as well as a pre-compiled version and then you can change variables in javascript and recompile the Less files in the users browser.

Comment: i was searching around for your suggestion but i cant find anything related to less and scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following library.https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/fixed.html